# Get a token to call Spring Boot controller which uses Azure AD

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am following this tutorial to secure a Java web app using the Spring Boot Starter for Azure Active Directory

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory

In the tutorial, they ask to open http://localhost:8080/Admin in a web browser and one should be prompted for a user name and password, and after one have logged in successfully, on should be able to see the text coming from the Spring controller

My question is, how do I test this from Postman or curl? Do I have to get a token first and then call the Spring Boot API? How?

Comment: is this document helps you :https://www.digitalonus.com/securing-a-restful-api-using-spring-boot-and-microsofts-azure-active-directory/